# Read multiple .csv files from folder with variable part fo file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder that contains a variable number of files, and each file has a variable string in the name. For example:

```
my_file V1.csv
my_file V2.csv
my_file something_else.csv
```

I would need to:

1. Load all the files which name start with "my_file"
2. Concatenate all of them in a single dataframe

Right now I am doing it with individual pd.read_csv functions for each file, and then merging them with a concatenate.

This is not optimal as every time the files in the source folder change, I need to modify the script.

Is it possible to automate this process, so that it works even if the source files change?

Comment: This question is already covered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `glob`, `pandas.concat` and `pandas.read_csv` fairly easily. Assuming the CSV files are in the same folder as your script:

```
import glob

import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob('my_file*.csv')])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
     if filename.startswith("my_file") and filename.endswith(".csv"): 
         # do some stuff here
         continue
     else:
         continue
```